# How to enable ServiceAppointmentGroup in salesforce?

Tags: field-service-lightning, health-cloud, crm

How to enable ServiceAppointmentGroup in salesforce. Is it part of Health cloud or Field service lightning?

Do we need to contact salesforce to enable this in sandbox, it is available in production.

Thanks

Comment: Is the sandbox in Spring`23 release ?

Answer (score 0):

ServiceAppointmentGroup is object related to the Health Cloud. Ideally this object should be visible for the org which have a feature called [Multi-Step Scheduling](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.admin_advanced_therapy_management_learn_about_multi_step_scheduling.htm&type=5) enabled.

But we had an unexpected behaviour starting Winter`23 due to which this feature was enabled on all the orgs even on your sandboxes as well without actually you buying these licenses.

That behaviour was identified and this feature has been turned off automatically in the new Spring'23 release and that is why you are not seeing these objects in your Sandbox with Spring'23 preview.

If you need this feature you may need to contact Salesforce Support.